# tinyMCE API filter elements in tinymce.html.Node

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tinymce

tinyMCE Version: 4.9.4 https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/

I am using

```
var schema = tinymce.activeEditor.schema;
var parser = new tinymce.html.DomParser({validate: true}, schema);
var node = parser.parse(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
```

to get the content of a tinyMCE editor. Here is an example content:

```html
<h1>Heading</h1><p>This is  a paragraph.</p><p>This is another paragraph<br />with a soft return</p>
```

I want to access the text in all p-Elements, check their length and wrap a substring in a custom html-Element. E.G.

```html
<h1>Heading</h1><p>This<foo> is  a paragraph</foo>.</p><p>This<foo> is another paragraph<br />with a soft return</foo></p>
```

How can I access the text in all p-Elements in the Node object returned by the DomParser?

References:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/api/tinymce.html/tinymce.html.domparser/

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/api/tinymce.html/tinymce.html.node/

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.treewalker/

Answer (score 0):

addNodeFilter is a method of tinymce.html.DomParser. It collects nodes by name and execute a callback function. addNodefilter is called when tinymce.html.DomParser.parse() is called. I'm using the following code to print the text contained in p tags in an html string.

```
var schema = tinymce.activeEditor.schema;
var parser = new tinymce.html.DomParser({validate: true}, schema);
parser.addNodeFilter('p', function(nodes, name){
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        console.log(nodes[i].firstChild.value);
    }
});
parser.parse('<h1>Heading</h1><p>This is  a paragraph.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p>');
```

Output:

This is a paragraph.
This is another paragraph.

References:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/api/tinymce.html/tinymce.html.domparser/#addattributefilter